# How to alert a row or a group of rows in Beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

I would like to highlight different parts of my results table in a slide.

Trying something like this

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\alert<2>{
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
}
7 & 8 & 9\\
\end{tabular}
```

Always throws a  `Missing \endgroup inserted.` error in Beamer. 
I can't even get it working for a single row.

May I know if there is a way to alert a row or a group of rows in Beamer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{uncovering table rows}
\begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule}cccc}
Class & A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
\alert<2> X & \alert<2> 1 & \alert<2> 2 & \alert<2> 3 & \alert<2> 4 \\
\alert<2> Y & \alert<2> 3 & \alert<2> 4 & \alert<2> 5 & \alert<2> 6 \\
          Z & 5           & 6           & 7           & 8           \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

for details, see `beamer` documentation (User Guide for version 3.49.), page 219.

[image]

Comment: I figured that this was the last resort but was wondering whether there was a simpler straight-forward solution. To be precise, I have 2 tables with 14 rows and 7 columns wanted to do something like `\alert<2>{first 3 rows}` then `\alert<3>{next 8 rows}` and finally `\alert<4>{last 3 rows}` -- you can see how complicated the code would become if I were to follow this last resort.

Comment: do you read `beamer` manual? there is explained why this is not possible on another way. however, you can put complete table in `alert` environment.  using this approach, you need to redesign presentatio of your table (split them to subtables" ...)

Comment: You're right (just read page 219). We do have no other choice. I work with Emacs (AucTeX); at least the macro automation in it alleviates the code writing a little.

Comment: That  gives me `Command \itshape invalid in math mode. `

Comment: @BeniBela, where you have/found this command? (in my MWE)?